# Learning to work with a rotary tool

Tags: wood, tool-usage

More or less by occasion as I searched for something original I could craft myself, I decided to craft a [walnut jewelry box](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rdWFBY37BEw) for the proposal. It went well! :-)

[image]

For this purpose I had bought a *[rotary tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_grinder)* accompanied with a set of drill and sandpaper bits.

Now I ask myself how to explore and study more what I could do with this rotary tool but in a more systematic way than jumping from one YT tutorial to another.

I like the wording from the [Arts&Crafts movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arts_and_Crafts_movement) regarding exposing the natural beauty of materials. While I am not a great artist, I think I could learn to craft more or less simple things.

Local makers DIY shop has more electronics/hardware background than arts and crafts. Maybe there is a good entry level book to start with?

Comment: Congratulations! Wishing you and your fiancé(e) the very best!

Comment: Put on glasses and use it , you will find out how to use. If you are going to decorate walnut shells there is no reason to learn how to grind steel.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a local makers DIY shop, so that is probably your best bet.
If it's current membership don't focus on crafts, just ask the leadership if you can start a craft night.  Volunteer to teach people how to make that walnut jewelry box during the first meeting.  Then at the end of the meeting, ask for other presenters to teach on other craft subjects.  With a little luck, you could build a thriving craft community very quickly.  Somewhere in that growing community, you will find the rotary tool teacher who can help you master it in an orderly fashion.

Beyond that, the best way to master a tool is to use it.
Find tasks which need doing where your rotary tool can play a part.  Then research on YT how to apply the rotary tool to that task.  Each new task completed increases your skill with the tool and in a surprisingly short time, you will have more new tricks to teach to your growing craft community.